# Proofs of Norms in Quadratic Field

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Question**

Suppose $α$ and $β$ are elements of $Q[√d]$. Show that $N(αβ) = N(α)N(β)$ and that $N(α/β)=N(α)/N(β)$. In the case where $α ∈ Q$, show that $N(α) = α^2$.

**My Work**

For the first two can someone verify?

[image]

I don't know how to do the last part. Can someone help me?

Comment: The last part is easier because $\bar{\alpha}=\alpha$

Comment: If by $\bar\alpha$ you mean the complex conjugate, your formula for norm is not generally correct. You should work with $\sqrt d$ directly.

Comment: The norm is the determinant of the linear transformation $x\mapsto \alpha x$. Both properties are just the property of determinants $\det(\alpha\beta)=\det(\alpha)\det(\beta)$.

Comment: For the case of the quadratic field extension your proof is correct.

Comment: @John The conjugation presumably denotes the conjugation automorphism of the quadratic field, so the proof is fine. What do you mean by "work with $\,\sqrt d\,$ directly"?

Comment: @BillDubuque I am assuming based on the question that the OP is a student for whom doing things in a relatively concrete and literal way would be useful. Surely under the appropriate interpretation of the symbols, the manipulation is correct.